# Number of samples needed as input to Bernoulli factory

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, bernoulli-trial

Let $\{X_i\}$ denote an i.i.d. sequence of Bernoulli variables with parameter $p$. A Bernoulli factory is a procedure that generates events with probability $f(p)$ using the observations $\{X_i\}$, where $f$ is a known function and $p$ is assumed to be unknown.

Is there some general result, or bound, on the number of samples of $\{X_i\}$ needed by a Bernoulli factory?

Some simple examples:

- ($f(p) = p^2$) To generate an event with probability $p^2$ it's sufficient to use two samples of the original sequence $\{X_i\}$. Actually less on average, because if the first of those two samples is $0$ you don't need the second.
- ($f(p) = \sqrt p$) The algorithm at the top of page 7 of [this paper](http://www.math.chalmers.se/~wastlund/coinFlip.pdf) generates an event of probability $\sqrt p$. The number of samples of $\{X_i\}$ used by that procedure can be easily computed.
- There are some general approaches for arbitrary $f$, for example [this one](http://arxiv.org/abs/0907.4018) using martingales.

So, given a function $f$ and a procedure that generates an event that has probability $f(p)$, how can one know if that's the *best* procedure, in the sense of using the least possible number of observations $X_i$ (on average) that is possible? Or, failing that, are there some *bounds* on that number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two references come to mind:

http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0309222

http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0304143

The gist of it is, if I remember it right, that fast implementation is possible iff f is real-analytic.

Comment: Thanks! The entropy bound referred to in reference 1 is in line with what I wanted. I'll wait for a while in case there's some answer with a better result/bound

Answer (score 0):

I made some progress with this.

Let $N$ be the number of inputs consumed by the Bernoulli factory. If $f$ is differentiable, any factory that is fast in the sense of [Nacu-Peres](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoap/1106922322) (i.e. $\Pr[N \geq n]$ is exponentially bounded) has
$$
\mathrm E[N] \geq (f'(p))^2 \frac{p(1-p)}{f(p)(1-f(p))}.
$$
This is theorem 3 from [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304414918306768?via%3Dihub) (also on [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.08923)). The proof is based on the fact that the factory output is a sequential estimator of $f(p)$, to which [Wolfowitz](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177730439)'s extension of the Cramér-Rao bound can be applied.